# Error : Invalid conversion

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and this is the error I keep getting and I have no idea what it is. It says that at the *display* function line. It has this error
**invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]|**
May I know what is the meaning of this error and how to solve it ?

```
void passChar()
{
    char letter[] = {'H','E','L','L','O','!'};
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            display(letter[i]);
            swapLetter(letter[i]);
        }
    }



}
```

Here is my display function

```
void display(char letter[])
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        switchStatement(letter[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is my swapletter function

```
void swapLetter(char letter[])
{
    char temp = letter[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        letter[i-1] = letter[i];
    }
    letter[5]= temp;
}
```

My aim is to have endless loop for the word hello.

Comment: " at the display function line " can u post display function too

Comment: First of all you should show us the prototypes of `display` and `swapLetter`. Also, even if you get it to compile, you will be stuck in your `while(true)`-endless-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invalid in whole because this loop

```
    while(true)
    {
        display(letter[i]);
        swapLetter(letter[i]);
    }
```

is infinite unless either display or swapLetter does not have call to exit.

As for error then it is obvious from the error message that the function expects to get some string instead of on character. So its parameter is declared something as char s[] or char *s, or const char s[], or const char *s and so on.
And even if you would pass to it your array letter it would be a mistake because your array has no the terminating zero. I think you should declare your array as

```
char letter[] = {'H','E','L','L','O','!', '\0'};
```

Or function display should be declared as

```
void display( char c );
```

Comment: char letter[] = "HELLO!"; is the idiomatic way

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are passing a `char` as a parameter to a function that expects `char*`.

Your functions actually expect you to pass the entire string rather than a single character. So your code should be:

```
display(letter);
swapLetter(letter);
```

Of course, I suspect that renders the outer loop in `passChar` meaningless. And the infinite `while(true)` loop seems odd, although you claim in the question that it is intentional. In which case the code should read:

```
void passChar()
{
    char letter[] = {'H','E','L','L','O','!'};
    while(true)
    {
        display(letter);
        swapLetter(letter);
    }
}
```

Personally I think I would code `display` and `swapLetter` to accept `char*` and use the null-terminator to detect length.

```
void passChar()
{
    char letter[] = "HELLO!";
    while(true)
    {
        display(letter);
        swapLetter(letter);
    }
}
```

and then modify `display` and `swapLetter` to use the null-terminator to locate the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because your `display()` function looks like the following:

```
void display(char* value)
{ }
```

`letter[i]` is of type `char`, the above function expects `char*`...

Comment: I have added my display function above. Please have a look